# How do you catch the intent for opening a web page?

Tags: android

I am trying to catch the intent that is fired when someone clicks on a hyperlink to a web page in the Mms browser. I have this in the manifest:

```
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
```

However, when I click on http://www.ibm.com it only launches Browser. Same when I do 
$ am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d http://www.ibm.com
in an adb shell. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks very much,
c

Comment: In fact just the following is working now, both in emulator and adp. Not sure what I had wrong:
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copy the intent-filter lines from the [Browser's manifest](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Browser.git;a=blob;f=AndroidManifest.xml;h=3d970ab3984bb06057a6ca756cb59b7738581967;hb=HEAD) and it will work:

```
        <!-- For these schemes were not particular MIME type has been
             supplied, we are a good candidate. -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:scheme="about" />
            <data android:scheme="javascript" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!--  For these schemes where any of these particular MIME types
              have been supplied, we are a good candidate. -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:scheme="inline" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/html"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/xhtml+xml"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml"/>
        </intent-filter>
```